# NullPointerException in Clojure reduce method

Tags: clojure

I am struggling with a NPE in my first Clojure program and would like some help.

`call-elem` is a struct which contains:-

- `:id`, a string like `some.packagename.SomeClass.someMethod`
- `:calls` (children), a vector of other `call-elem` structs

is defined as follows:

```
(defstruct call-struct :id :calls)

(defn- class-name [call]
  (let [id (call :id)]
    (.substring id 0 (.lastIndexOf id "."))))

(defn- method-name [call]
  (let [id (call :id)]
    (.substring id (inc (.lastIndexOf id ".")))))
```

I also have a method `foo` which takes a `class-map` and a `call-elem` as arguments. `class-map` is a map of `class-name` to `method-map`. `method-map` is a map of `method-name` to a list of `variation`s. Each `variation` is a map with keys `:class-name`, `:method-name` and `:calls`. `:calls` is a list of other variations. The `foo` function should return a vector with two elements:-

- the first element is a class-map with new entries corresponding to the `call-elem` and its children
- the second element is a variation map corresponding to the argument `call-elem`

Here is the code:

```
(declare foo' add-new-variation)

(defn foo [class-map call-elem]
  (let [children (call-elem :calls)
        class-name (class-name call-elem)
        method-name (method-name call-elem)]
    (if (empty? children)
      (let [new-variation {:class-name class-name
                           :method-name method-name
                           :calls []}
            new-class-map (add-new-variation class-map 
                                             class-name method-name 
                                             new-variation)]
        [new-class-map new-variation])
      (let [[new-class-map child-variations-list] 
            (reduce #(foo' %1 %2) (class-map '()) children)
            new-variation {:class-name class-name
                           :method-name method-name
                           :calls child-variations-list}
            new-class-map' (add-new-variation new-class-map 
                                              class-name method-name 
                                              new-variation)]
        [new-class-map' new-variation]))))

(defn foo' [[class-map variations-list] call-elem]
  (let [[new-class-map new-variation] (foo class-map call-elem)]
    [new-class-map (cons new-variation variations-list)]))

(defn add-new-variation [class-map class-name method-name variation]
  (let [method-map (if (contains? class-map class-name)
                     (class-map class-name) {})
        variations-list (if (contains? method-map method-name)
                          (method-map method-name) [])
        new-variations-list (conj variations-list variation)
        new-method-map (assoc method-map method-name new-variations-list)]
    (assoc class-map class-name new-method-map)))
```

When I try to run the following code:

```
(try
  (let [call-elem 
        (struct call-struct "Class1.method1" 
                [(struct call-struct "Class2.method1" [])])]
    (second (foo {} call-elem)))
  (catch Exception ex
         (.printStackTrace ex)))
```

I get the following result:

```
{:class-name "Class1",
 :method-name "method1",
 :calls ({:class-name "Class2", :method-name "method1", :calls []})}
```

But when I try to run the following code, increasing the calls one level deeper, I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
(try
  (let [call-elem 
        (struct call-struct "Class1.method1" 
                [(struct call-struct "Class2.method1"
                         [(struct call-struct "Class3.method1" [])])])]
    (second (foo {} call-elem)))
  (catch Exception ex
         (.printStackTrace ex)))
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at first.simple$foo.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:46)
    at first.simple$foo_SINGLEQUOTE_.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:55)
    at first.simple$foo$fn__1986.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:46)
    at clojure.lang.ArrayChunk.reduce(ArrayChunk.java:58)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5565.invoke(protocols.clj:30)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5543$G__5538__5552.invoke(protocols.clj:11)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:5995)
    at first.simple$foo.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:46)
    at first.simple$eval2010.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:6)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clooj.repl$create_clojure_repl$repl_thread_fn__578$fn__589.invoke(repl.clj:147)
    at clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__5967.invoke(main.clj:244)
    at clojure.main$repl$fn__5972.invoke(main.clj:265)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:265)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1523)
    at clooj.repl$create_clojure_repl$repl_thread_fn__578.invoke(repl.clj:145)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the `reduce` in `foo`. I suspect you're trying to pass a two-element collection as an initial value of `reduce`'s accumulator. However using unquoted parentheses causes `(class-map '())` to be treated as an expression to be evaluated. To make matters worse, it's valid, as `class-map` is a `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`, which implementents `IFn`.

As a result, instead of creating a two element list you're calling `(class-map '())`, which most probably returns `nil`, as there's no `'()` key in `class-map`. Afterwards, in `foo'` you're trying to bind a `nil` to `[class-map variations-list]`. Boom. Null pointer exception.

Defining the second argument of `reduce` as a vector should solve the problem.

```
--- before  2011-12-27 12:52:43.052218334 +0100
+++ after   2011-12-27 12:52:56.785477270 +0100
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@
                                              new-variation)]
         [new-class-map new-variation])
       (let [[new-class-map child-variations-list]
-            (reduce #(foo' %1 %2) (class-map '()) children)
+            (reduce #(foo' %1 %2) [class-map '()] children)
             new-variation {:class-name class-name
                            :method-name method-name
                            :calls child-variations-list}
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks! Do you have any recommendations on improving the code? As I said, this is my first attempt at Clojure, so any suggestions are welcome. :)